# C# MixerOpen with Callback function

Tags: c#, mixer

I am trying to open the sound card mixers with the API:

```
lRet = mixerOpen(ref hmixer, uMxId, cbFunction, IntPtr.Zero, MIXER_OBJECTF_MIXER
    | CALLBACK_FUNCTION);
```

where `cbFunction` is a pointer to a function that will receive the `MM_MIXM_LINE_CHANGE` and `MM_MIXM_CONTROL_CHANGE` mixer messages but I am not able to set up such a function.

I have already done a lot of web search without any success and now you are my last hope ...

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!!

... after many hours of web search, just as soon as I sent my message, I found this excellent article
 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22953/A-Synchronized-Volume-Control-for-your-Application
by Maurice Tarrant; he will always have my warmest Acknowledgments.

Ciao, Maurice, with many thanks again.

Franco